# Adding Multiple records in single save using visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

> Error: **MultipleAccountsRecord line 9, column 6: The end-tag for
>   element type "a" must end with a '>' delimiter**   Error: **The end-tag
>   for element type "a" must end with a '>' delimiter.**

VF code:

```
<apex:page controller="AddmultipleAccountController">
  <apex:form>
  <apex:pageBlock>
  <apex:pageBlockTable="{!ListAccount}" var="a" >
    <apex:inputField value="{!a.name}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!a.AccountNumber}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!a.Type}"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!a.Industry}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
  <apex:pageBlockButtons>
   <apex:commandButton value="Add Accounts Row" action="{!addAccount}"/>
   <apex:commandButton value="Save Accounts" action="{!saveAccount}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
   </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page
```

Apex class:

```
public class AddmultipleAccountController {
 public List<Account> ListAccount{get; set;}

  public AddmultipleAccountController(ApexPages.StandardController myController) 

  {
  ListAccount = new List<Account>();
   Account acc= new Account();
  ListAccount.add(acc);
  }

  public void addAccount()
  {
  Account acc= new Account();
  ListAccount.add(acc);
  }

  public PageReference saveAccount()
  {
  for(integer i=0; i<ListAccount.size(); i++)
  {
  insert ListAccount;
  }
  return Page.AllAccountssaved;
}

}
```

Comment: This looks like a compile-time error in the page. Check the page at line 9.

Answer (score 0):

There a quite a few changes you need to do in controller and visualforce page for this to work.

- There is a compilation error in `visualforce` page where you have not mentioned the `value` attribute of `PageBlockTable`. You have to provide the `value` attribute in `PageBlockTable` i.e. `<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ListAccount}" var="a" >`
- You have not closed the `page` tag properly in `visualforce` page i.e. you missed the closing `>`, I hope that is just an typo, but I thought I should mention that as well, so it will be `</apex:page>`
- You should have the `<apex:column>` tag inside `PageBlockTable`, whereas you directly used `<apex:inputField>`
- You are using the wrong `constructor` for `controller`, the `constructor` that you used is actually used by the `extension controller`. The `custom controller's constructor` does not have any `parameters`, so your `controller constructor's` signature will be `public AddmultipleAccountController()`
- Also, you are inserting the `list` in `for loop` which is incorrect, this will `insert` the duplicate records. Hence, you should not use `for loop` in your `saveAccount` method.

So overall your visualforce page would be

```
<apex:page controller="AddmultipleAccountController">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ListAccount}" var="a" >
            <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.name}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Account Number">
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.AccountNumber}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Type">
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.Type}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Industry">
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.Industry}"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandButton value="Add Accounts Row" action="{!addAccount}"/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Save Accounts" action="{!saveAccount}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And your controller should be

```
public class AddmultipleAccountController {
    public List<Account> ListAccount{get; set;}
    public AddmultipleAccountController(){
        ListAccount = new List<Account>();
        Account acc= new Account();
        ListAccount.add(acc);
    }

    public void addAccount(){
        Account acc= new Account();
        ListAccount.add(acc);
    }

    public PageReference saveAccount(){
        insert ListAccount;
        return Page.AllAccountssaved;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @user68935 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.